# How to add checkboxes in a Navigationview menu dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm trying to make a navigation drawer with a list of ingredients with checkboxes manually, because I load them from sqlite.

This is my method to load the names of the elements and it works, but I don't know how to add checkboxes to them with their respective OnCheckedChangeListener.

```
private void configView() {
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
    NavigationView navigationView = this.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    List<String> allTypes = db.ingredients(this);

    for (String types: allTypes) {
        SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(types);
        List<Ingredients> list = db.ingredientsByType(this, types);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            submenu.add(ingredientsByType.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the article about customization Menu items. It should help you.
[Using Custom Views As Menu Items](https://stablekernel.com/article/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/)

Comment: This does not help me, there is nothing about the checkboxes , but thanks for the info :(

Comment: In that article change this xml R.layout.view_alertsbadge.xml. Set checkbox inside instead of that content.